# Malloc vs character arrays of a specific size

Tags: c

First off I am pretty new to C, so I probably just have a fundamental misunderstanding here.  Given code such as this:

```
int main()
{
    char ack[100];
    char *bar;
    bar = malloc(100);
    strncpy(ack, "testing", 7);    
    bar = "testing";

    return 0;
}
```

`ack` when examined by gdb looks like this:

```
(gdb) p ack
$1 = "testing\000\360WV\000\000\000\000\000\277\000\000\000\000\000\000      
'\000'\000\220\005@",<repeats 13 times>, "\003\004@", '\000' <repeats 13 times>    
"\325,\005@\000\000\000\000\000H\214\246\367\377\177\000\000\220\005@",
'\000' <repeats 13 times>,     "P\004@\000\000\000\000\000\360\342\377\377"`
```

This makes sense to me given how I initialized `ack`.  What I don't quite get is why `bar` looks like this:

```
(gdb) p bar
$2 = 0x40066c "testing"
```

I allocated the same amount of storage (as far as I know) as I did when I requested space for `ack` but malloc doesn't have the extra junk.  As I understand it, malloc doesn't do any sort of data initialization or anything, so I'm a bit confused.  The reason that this came up is an issue I was having with strstr.  Basically, when I would read in data from a file (fgets), to a char array with a specific size strstr() would fail (which I was assuming was because of the extra junk).  Working with a pointer and malloc'd memory worked just fine.  Anyway, I have a few specific questions.

1. Is the behavior of this malloc'd variable expected? Is there some optimization going on here (I compiled with gcc, but didn't do any optimizations) or is gdb not showing me everything?  Should there be "junk" associated with that variable?
2. Am I even using malloc correctly?  Should I be initializing all of the memory I requested?  If so, how?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

Thanks to everyone who responded! I've learned quite a few things from you all and it's much appreciated.  I now see the problem with the code I posted above, and the original issue that I was having with fgets() and strstr().

Comment: memory is not filled with nulls when it is allocated. To do that use memset(..)

Comment: @Adrian, no, no no. This is `C`. Don't cast `malloc()`, and don't teach people new to `C` to do so.

Comment: @DanFego I'm learning too I guess haha. I've always casted mallocs. Thanks for the info. I've edited my comment!

Comment: @Adrian sorry for the yelling! I just see so many people here suggest that, I hate to think we're teaching beginners to do it too. :P

Comment: @Adrian: Pre-C89, `malloc` returned `char *`, so in those days a cast was necessary, and of course any tutorials or references written then would show it.  With C89, `malloc` was changed to return `void *`, which can be implicitly converted to any object pointer type, so the cast is now redundant (and may actually hide an error).  Unfortunately, a lot of those older references weren't updated to reflect the change, and the practice has persisted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
bar = "testing";
```

*re-assigns the pointer* `bar` to point to a static buffer holding the string `"testing"`, i.e. it no longer points to your `malloc`'d array. This is a [memory leak](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

To get a string into the `malloc`'d buffer, use `strcpy`, `strncpy` or `memcpy`, like you did with `ack`.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you (unintentionally) throw away the `malloc`ed memory when you assign

```
bar = "testing";
```

That makes `bar` point to the string literal and no longer to the (leaked) `malloc`ed memory.

Comment: Hm, `throw away` has a connotation of intention, so that's a point for `forget about`. On the other hand, `forget about` doesn't sound dramatic enough for a memory leak. I compromised.

Comment: Perfect! We also would have accepted "lose", "leak", "drop", "ignore", and "jettison as space junk".

Answer (score 0):

You're off on a couple of points.

First, the reason `ack` has garbage after "testing" when printed is because you never NULL-terminated it. In `C`, all strings must be NULL-terminated, i.e. end with `\0`. You can either remedy this here by calling `strncpy()` with length 8 (`strlen("testing") + 1) or just using`strcpy().

Second, `bar` looks different in `gdb` because it's a pointer to a `char`, while `ack` is a straight-up `char` array. `gdb` shows you the pointer value for `bar`, but also does you a favor by showing you what's on the other side of that pointer if it can, as you can see. And when you do `bar = "testing;"`, you're re-assigning what `bar` points to to a character array containing "testing" in memory. When you using string literals like that, it automatically has a `\0` character at the end, so is NULL-terminated, and hence doesn't have the garbage afterward.

Answer (score -1):

C strings have a null terminator (ascii character value zero) so the C string "testing" is actually 8 bytes long including the terminator.

When you print the original value it stops printing when it reaches the terminator.

But because you only copied the first 7 characters, when you print the second value it keeps printing junk until it reaches a zero in the garbage data that was there before.

Comment: Then again, maybe it was Daniel's explanation ;-) It was technically true though, I don't think I deserved a downvote.